# Can I reinstall or upgrade Android?

Tags: updates

At the moment I have a rooted Samsung GT-S5570. After I rooted it, I noticed that it started to be slower than it used to be.

I have had this phone for over two years. I update my computer's operating system once a year. I am thinking of doing something similar with my smartphone.

At the moment I am running Android 2.2.1. I think that an upgrade would not be ideal due to old hardware. What is the best option? To reinstall Android 2.2.1 or upgrade to a newer version?

In either case, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to "refresh" it, you could try a [factory-reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info), which will essentially revert it to a "blank state" (i.e. remove all user-data and user installed apps), so you can start over with a fresh system. You should however create a good backup beforehand – which is not an easy task with Android prior to ICS (pre-4.0). On the other had, this can be done without any "modifications" (such as [rooting](/questions/tagged/rooting) or the like).

If you consider updating your device, take a closer look at custom roms like [CyanogenMod](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/cyanogenmod/info). There might be other ROMs available which are tuned specifically for your device, and thus giving better performance even with a newer version of Android. This installation process however is a bit more "technical", and in most cases requires rooting the device and installing a custom recovery.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I really like *CyangenMod*. I am just gathering information on how to do it!

Comment: Check out their website. They often have pretty detailed instructions, specific to the device (if officially supported). If your device is not officially supported, check at XDA, they often have "inofficial ports" (which is where I've got mine), including instructions and community-support (forum).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom recovery such as ClockWorkMod Recovery or Team Win Recovery Project, you can first make a nandroid backup (which saves **all** of your current data to your SD card). Then you could complete a factory reset (either from Android itself or from your custom recovery). Finally, get an app like [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) or [Nandroid Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h3r3t1c.bkrestore) to retrieve your old apps and data.

As for installing a custom ROM, you may want to check out your device specific forum at [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/). Note that custom ROMs may not be as stable as the one you currently have. They could be unstable or even brick your phone. Flash with caution.

Also, since you have root, have you tried deleting the bloatware that comes with the phone (if there is any)? An app like Titanium Backup should do the trick. Your phone should feel faster after that is done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What exactly is a *bloatware*? Can *Titanium Backup* back up my contact phone list?

Comment: Bloatware is what "bloats" your device: all those apps the manufacturer/carrier/distributor added, and the user cannot remove. For details, please visit our [bloatware tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/bloatware/info) :) // And yes, there's almost nothing TiBu can not back up. It's the most complete backup solution, and full of additional features. First thing to put on a rooted device!